Unmarshal Isn't Working When Using Query Method In SurrealDB
I've written the following method to try to query SurrealDB from Go. When I use Unmarshal to put result into listing it isn't doing anything. listing isn't being populated but it also isn't showing any errors. This pattern has worked when I was using db.Select to get 1 or more rows so I am not sure what I should be doing here. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

type Listing struct {
    Id    string `json:"id,omitempty"`
    City  string `json:"city"`
    State string `json:"state"`
}

func singleRecordDynamic() {
    db := surreal.CreateConnection()
    defer db.Close()

    // First we query to get our record - This is a specific ID from the listing table
    result, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE city = $city", map[string]string{
        "city": "New York",
    })

    fmt.Println(result)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Now we create the instance of the object we want to put the result of our query into
    var listing []Listing
    // Now we use Unmarshal to put the query request into that instance
    err = surrealdb.Unmarshal(result, &listing)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Look now we can do things with it
    fmt.Println(listing[0])
}


surrealdb.Unmarshal does no more than deserializes your query result into JSON, then unmarshaling this JSON to a slice.
What exactly do you get as result of your db query?

The output of result is [map[result:[map[city:New York id:listings:hs6gio7smalyygb5cxfd state:Michigan]] status:OK time:123.417µs]]

Great. Now what do you expect to get after Unmarshal? What's the definition of the Listing struct (I assume it is a struct object)?

I updated to include the definition of Listing. I'm expecting it to fill in the values for listing. When I query Surreal using db.Select("listings") and run it through Unmarshal it populates listing.

You miss closing quotes after city in the definition of Listing
Must be json:"city"

And your query output does not have valid JSON format. I assume your codebase has to include implementations of custom MarshalJSON and UnmarshalJSON methods for Listing struct.
It makes sense to check whether Listings.MarshalJSON produces valid JSON output for your query result.
Just guessing, you know

I added the quote. It still doesn't work as expected
